can one extend mod operation to matrices?
when studying integer we have mod operation like:
$a = b k + r, |r|<|b| , a,b,k,r\in \Bbb Z$
and when learning polynomials we have mod operation like:
$ P(x) = Q(x)K(x) + R(x) $
where the degree of $R(x)$ is less than the degree of $Q(x)$
then is it possible to extend this operation to matrices?Like:
$A = BK +R$
where $A,B,K,R$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $R$ has some property less than $B$

Maybe you want to read about Euclidean domains: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain

It's not "order" of a polynomial, it's "degree".

The answer is both yes and no, depending on the level of abstract algebra that you're comfortable with.
In the "elementary" sense, i.e. without some machinery from abstract algebra, the answer is: no (for example, the first stumbling block is that matrix multiplication is not commutative so, in your notation, $B*K+R$ and $K*B+R$ may be different things).
In a more "advanced" sense, the answer is: in some cases, yes. See e.g. On some Euclidean properties of matrix algebras by Pierre Lezowski.

In a sense, the lack of commutativity is not a big problem since we can impose an order like $A=BK+R$, or define "left-quotient" ($A=KB+R$) and "right-quotient" ($A=BK+R$).

As another example, possibly closer to yours, if you fix a Hermitian matrix $A=S\Lambda S^T$, then you can define polynomials over it as $p(A) = S p(\Lambda)S^T$, where $A=S\Lambda S^T$ is the eigenvalue decomposition. Then, the usual modulo operation you wrote would be meaningful, similar to polynomials over a scalar field:
$$A^2+3A-1=(A-1)(A+1)+3A\,.$$
